# How do I test a Spring Integration Transformer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am new to Spring Integration (been using Spring before). I have made a transformer like this:

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "signering", outputChannel = "validering")
```

and now I want to test it. So I have done like this in my test:

```
@Autowired
MessageChannel signering;

@Autowired
PollableChannel validering;
```

When I invoke the transformer in my test it seems to work

```
signering.send(msg.build());
```

but I am unable to intercept the outgoing message (which is what I want). Instead it seems to go to the real bean validering and onwards. I have added a .receive call after the send call, but it gets nothing. And the Internet is not really helpful right now. What examples I find for Spring Integration testing seems to be using XML context, and they are pretty old at that. What is the current way of doing this kind of testing?

Answer (score 0):

In your test case, add a `ChannelInterceptor` to the output channel, before sending the request, to examine the output.

Comment: Well, that does enable me to examine the message. But the message is still passed down the chain, so it's not really making this an isolated test.

Also, is this really the best practice way to write tests for Spring Integration? Seems there are very few examples of actual tests out there.

Comment: See the javadocs for `ChannelInterceptor`; if `preSend()` returns `null`, the flow ends.